# outlook for salesforce not getting configured

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook

I'm trying to configure Salesforce for Outlook. I have downloaded and installed the software and then when I;m trying to run it I'm getting this :

[image]

I'm using the Microsoft Outlook 365 Pro Plus. Is there something I'm skipping? Or isn't my Outlook compatible for using this feature?

Comment: The error is descriptive enough! Click on the configuration link and proceed with it.

Comment: @RahulSharma I did ! but those options are grayed out!!

Comment: What does your outlook configuration say in your org?